# Installed PostgreSQL and cannot get the pgAdmin to open

Tags: windows, pgadmin-4

This is the error I get when I try to open pgAdmin 4. I installed the PostgresSQL 13 which is latest. I did the HKEY fix, cleared temp folders under AppData and ran as admin and nothing. I need to create a database and table. How do I do that if I can't even open pgAdmin.
New to this.

pgAdmin Runtime Environment

---

Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"

Environment:
   • ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
   • APPDATA: C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming
   • CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \.\pipe\crashpad_10156_OYIAWLFFYJSPWPGP
   • CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Whoa! NW.js has crashed. Relaunch now?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
   • CLIENTNAME: DEVWS030
   • CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
   • CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
   • CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
   • COMPUTERNAME: VA-SCRD-TUAW02
   • ComSpec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
   • DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
   • HOMEDRIVE: C:
   • HOMEPATH: \Users[user]
   • LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local
   • LOGONSERVER: \VA-COLO-DC1
   • NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 2
   • OS: Windows_NT
   • Path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
   • PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
   • PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 6faa2add-9f1c-4745-acde-7cf728e0b4b6
   • PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 58801
   • PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
   • PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
   • PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
   • PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
   • PROCESSOR_REVISION: 2d07
   • ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
   • ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
   • ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
   • ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
   • PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
   • PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
   • SESSIONNAME: RDP-Tcp#1
   • SystemDrive: C:
   • SystemRoot: C:\Windows
   • TEMP: C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\2
   • TMP: C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\2
   • USERDNSDOMAIN: xx
   • USERDOMAIN: xx
   • USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: xx
   • USERNAME: reena.ponnengada
   • USERPROFILE: C:\Users\reena.ponnengada
   • windir: C:\Windows

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 98, in 
    app = create_app()
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_*init*_.py", line 347, in create_app
    if not os.path.exists(SQLITE_PATH) or get_version() == -1:
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup\db_version.py", line 19, in get_version
    return version.value
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: i'm having the exact same issue, tried installing different versions of postgresql and they all did the same - EDIT: OK. I downloaded and installed pgadmin4 V5.0 (not the lastest one) from https://www.pgadmin.org/download/ then cleaned C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin and it worked for me.
BTW i'm using postgre 9.6. seen in this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527280/get-fatal-error-server-could-not-be-contacted-when-running-pgadmin4-nonetype

Answer (score 2):

This error typically occurs after updates of either PostgreSQL or PgAdmin.
What worked for me was deleting the folder ***C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin.***
Then re-install pgAdmin and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it happens because the pgAdmin 4 port number is used by another application or service on your PC. You can see a configure button below the error message.

Just click the configure button, and it will open a window that shows the option to change your port number.

Enter a random port number and hit save. If the number is already in use, it will show an error. Otherwise, it will save.

Finally, restart pgAdmin 4. It worked for me.